# How to create standalone jar from javafx project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jar

I've tried ot do this for what seems like forever, and haven't found a way. The things i've tried so far:
Using fx:deploy : not avalible in new JDKs
Using Maven : couldn't figure it out completly, didn't get it to work
Using IntelliJ's normal artifact packaging.

These methods all produced jars, but none of them worked. Creating the jar with method 3 would only work if i ran it from the command line, specifing module dependencies. How would I do this without having to run it from the command line, and without having people if they want to use it to install javafx. Just java. Any way to do this? Let me know if anyone has any clarifying questions. The jar dosen't need to be executable, just able to be ran without dependencies, from any other normal method.

Comment: When you say it didn't work what do you mean?  Please provide any errors and anything else that will help with reproducing your problem or leading to a solution.

Comment: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX.

Comment: @MrR one error i got was `Java FX Packager: Can't build artifact - fx:deploy is not available in this JDK` for fx deploy. I mainly mean that the jar didn't work and the reason behind it was that the dependencies weren't in it. That's my problem. LMK more questions

Comment: @AwesomeDude3247 have you seen this questions answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53450011/build-and-deploy-javafx-application-using-java11?

Comment: @MrR no I have not, i'll check it out

Comment: @MrR so i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62225885/14035203) solution, and it looked promising, but then I got [this](https://gist.github.com/OfficialAwesomeDude/be3da73bdeaf3217dc12f96b34264823) error from when i tried to run it. Any solutions?

Comment: @AwesomeDude3247 if you're running on linux - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63320296 or have you [set JAVA_HOME](https://linuxtut.com/if-you-get-a-quantum-renderer-no-suitable-pipeline-found-error-when-running-the-jar-file-b0514/)?